# Why is my PHP AJAX onclick function not always triggering?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, onclick

I'm having problems with an A HTML element `onclick` function in PHP AJAX.

```
foreach(array_unique($_SESSION["items"]) as $item) {

     echo '<a onclick="minItem('. $item .');" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 ">-</a>
}
```

This code means to remove 1 element from an array.

The code in my Javascript is as follows:

```
function minItem(item) 
{               
    var minus = item;

    $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "testing.php", 
    data: {'minus': minus},
    success: function(result){ 
      $("#cart_overview").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

For some of the elements in the array, this is working, e.g. when `$item = 122` for example. But when `$item = R323`, the AJAX function seems to not be called.

I've been looking for solutions but couldn't find any. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to quote the variable if it is a string - ie `cho '<a onclick="minItem(\''. $item .'\');"` ...etc

Comment: String seems to be the issue, if it's a number `javascript_function(111)` will work, but `R323` is a string, then `javascript_function(R323)` should not work, and the way you are generating the values for the JS function will write like that, i suggest you put all the values always in between simple quotes `'<a onclick="minItem(\'''. $item .'\');"` or soubles if u like

Comment: @FranciscoHahn Thanks for the suggestion, your code gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ".$item." (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I wrote from the cellphone, answer you were given should do the trick

Comment: :-) excellent - good luck with the rest of it

Comment: Don't you see an error in the Javascript console when the function fails? I think that would have clued you to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the onclick call could hold strings you need to wrap the passed parameter by quotes, like :

```
 echo "<a onclick='minItem(\"$item\");' class='btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0 '>-</a>";
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. It gives me an error: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: The first solution won't work. HTML doesn't understand escaped quotes inside attributes.

Comment: Yes right @Barmar, the second should work... (Updated)

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` tag need a `href` attribute and you need to quote any variable passed in to the `minItem` as an argument if the argument is a string - something like this perhaps:

```
foreach( array_unique( $_SESSION["items"] ) as $item ) {
    printf('<a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="minItem(\'%s\')">-</a>', $item );
}
```